# @JsonDeserialize not getting invoked when using spring

Tags: json, spring, jackson, cxf

I am using Jackson 2.x and spring-ws 4.0.6.
I have configured a rest service using CXF and configured mapper.

```
<jaxrs:providers>         
        <ref bean="jsonReader"/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

Then configured this mapper like this

```
<bean id="jsonBodyReader" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider">
    <property name="mapper" ref="mapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mapper"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotationIntrospector">
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector"/>
    </property>
    <property name="featuresToEnable">
        <array>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID"/>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES"/>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="featuresToDisable">
        <array>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS"/>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS"/>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES"/>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>
</bean>
```

Now I want to map this json to `List<HashMap<String,String>>`

```
{
"identities": [{
    "id1": "12345",
    "id2": "16777"
},{
    "id3": "12345"
}]
```

}

I can get as many `ids - id1, id2, id3..` so I cannot create a pojo with fields name `id1, id2` and so on.

I annotated the field in my POJO like this

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustDeserializer.class)
private List<HashMap<String,String>> identities;
```

`CustDeserializer` looks like this

```
public class CustDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer>> {
  @Override
  public List> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);
    List> identities = new ArrayList>();
    for(int i=0;i> elem = node1.fields();
        HashMap map= new HashMap();           
        while(elem.hasNext()){
            Entry el = elem.next();
            String name = el.getKey();
            String value = el.getValue().asText();
            map.put(name, value);
        }
        identities.add(map);
    }
    return identities;
  }
```

Now when I call the rest service, the list is populated with hashmaps containing key/value pairs. But `CustDeserializer` class is not invoked so I am not able to customize my list. It is getting transformed by Jackson's `CollectionDeserializer` by default.

When I try the same in a standalone java program, it works and my deserializer is called

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        JsonRequest h = mapper.readValue(new File("request.json"), JsonRequest.class);
        System.out.println(h);
    }
```

Output: `JsonRequest [name=XYZ, identities=[{id2=16777, id1=12345}, {id3=12345}]]`

But somehow it doesn't work when I am using it in the context of CXF and Spring.